# TypeError: path.split is not a function getting Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm trying to build a restaurant website. I already build half part of it. But I'm stuck at some point. I'm getting errors. I can't find out in my code what is wrong. Whenever I tried to add new food by clicking add button it added but whenever I click on the cart button to checkout visit the checkout page. Then I get:

> TypeError: path.split is not a function?.

I'm using react hook form.  I tried to debug but I'm getting the same errors many times. Can someone check it out, please?

**Here is my App.js File**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Banner from './components/Banner/Banner';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Foods from './components/Foods/Foods';
import Features from './components/Features/Features';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
// import SIgnUp from './components/SignUp/SIgnUp';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound/NotFound';

import FoodItemDetails from './components/FoodItemDetails/FoodItemDetails'
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';
import Shipment from './components/Shipment/Shipment';


export const userContext = createContext();

function App() {

  const [cart , setCart] = useState([]);
  const [orderId , setOrderId] = useState(null);
  
  const [deliveryDetails , setDeliveryDetails] = useState({
    todoor:null,road:null, flat:null, businessname:null, address: null
  });

  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState(null);
  const deliveryDetailsHandler = (data) => {
      setDeliveryDetails(data)
  }
  const getUserEmail = (email) => {
    setUserEmail(email);
  }

  const clearCart =  () => {
    const orderedItems = cart.map(cartItem => {
      return {food_id : cartItem.id, quantity: cartItem.quantity}
    })

    const orderDetailsData = { userEmail , orderedItems,  deliveryDetails }
    fetch('https://red-onion-backend.herokuapp.com/submitorder' , {
        method : "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(orderDetailsData)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data=> setOrderId(data._id))
    console.log(orderId);

    setCart([])
  }

  const cartHandler = (data) => {
    const alreadyAdded = cart.find(crt => crt.id == data.id );
    const newCart = [...cart,data]
    setCart(newCart);
    if(alreadyAdded){
      const reamingCarts = cart.filter(crt => cart.id != data);
      setCart(reamingCarts);
    }else{
      const newCart = [...cart,data]
      setCart(newCart);
    }
   
  }

  const checkOutItemHandler = (productId, productQuantity) => {
    const newCart = cart.map(item => {
      if(item.id == productId){
          item.quantity = productQuantity;
      }
      return item;
    })

    const filteredCart = newCart.filter(item => item.quantity > 0)
    setCart(filteredCart)
  }
 




  const [logggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState({});
  const [signOutUser, setSignOutUser] = useState({});
  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={([logggedInUser, setLoggedInUser], [signOutUser, setSignOutUser])}>
         <Router>
    <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">

      <Header cart={cart}></Header>
      <Banner></Banner>
      <Foods cart={cart}></Foods>
      <Features></Features>
      <Footer></Footer>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/user">
        <Login></Login>

      </Route>
      <Route path= "/food/:id">
        <Header cart={cart}></Header>
         
         
         {/* <FoodItemDetails cart={cart} cartHandler={cartHandler}></FoodItemDetails> */}
         <FoodItemDetails cart={cart} cartHandler={cartHandler}></FoodItemDetails>
         <Footer></Footer>

      </Route>
      <PrivateRoute path="/checkout">
        <Header cart={cart}></Header>
        <Shipment deliveryDetails={deliveryDetails} deliveryDetailsHandler={deliveryDetailsHandler} cart={cart} clearCart={clearCart} checkOutItemHandler={checkOutItemHandler} getUserEmail={getUserEmail}>

        </Shipment>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </PrivateRoute>
      
      <Route path ="*">
        <NotFound></NotFound>
      </Route>

    </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
     </userContext.Provider>
 
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Here is my Shipment.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Shipment = (props) => {

    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = data => {
        props.deliveryDetailsHandler(data);
        // props.getUserEmail(auth.user.email);
    };
    const { todoor, road, flat, businessname, address} = props.deliveryDetails;

    const subTotal = props.cart.reduce((acc,crr) => {
        return acc + (crr.price * crr.quantity) ;
    },0)
    const totalQuantity = props.cart.reduce((acc,crr) => {
        return acc + crr.quantity ;
    },0)
    const tax = (subTotal / 100) * 5;
    const deliveryFee = totalQuantity && 2;
    const grandTotal = subTotal + tax + deliveryFee;
    return (
<div className="shipment container pt-5 my-5">
            <div className="row">
                <div style={{display:(todoor && road && flat && businessname && address) ? "none" : "block"}} className="col-md-5">
                    <h4>Edit Delivery Details</h4>
                    <hr/>
                    <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="py-5">
                    
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input name="todoor" className="form-control" {...register( {requried: true})} defaultValue={todoor} placeholder="Delivery To Door"/>
                            {errors && errors.todoor && <span className="error">This Option is required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input name="road" className="form-control" {...register( {requried: true})} defaultValue={road} placeholder="Road No"/>
                            {errors && errors.road && <span className="error">Road No is required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input name="flat" className="form-control" {...register( {requried: true})} defaultValue={flat} placeholder="Flat, Suite or Floor"/>
                            {errors && errors.flat && <span className="error">Flat, Suite or Floor is required</span>}
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input name="businessname" className="form-control" {...register( {requried: true})} defaultValue={businessname} placeholder="Business name"/>
                            {errors && errors.businessname && <span className="error">Business name is required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <textarea name="address" {...register( {requried: true})} placeholder="Address" className="form-control" cols="30" rows="2">{address}</textarea>
                            {errors.address && <span className="error">Password is required</span>}
                        </div>
                        
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button className="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Save & Continue</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div style={{display:(todoor && road && flat && businessname && address) ? "block" : "none"}} className="col-md-5">
                    {/* <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                        <Payment markAsPaid={markAsPaid}/>
                    </Elements> */}
                </div>
                <div className="offset-md-2 col-md-5">
                    <div className="restaurant-info mb-5">
                        <h4>Form <strong> Star Kabab And Restaura</strong></h4>
                        <h5>Arriving in 20-30 min</h5>
                        <h5>107 Rd No 9</h5>
                    </div>
                   
                    {
                        props.cart.map(item => 
                            <div className="single-checkout-item mb-3 bg-light rounded d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between p-3">
                                <img width="100px" src={item.images[0]} alt=""/>
                                <div>
                                    <h6>{item.name}</h6>
                                    <h4 className="text-danger">${item.price.toFixed(2)}</h4>
                                    <p>Delivery free</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="checkout-item-button ml-3 btn">
                                    <button onClick={() => props.checkOutItemHandler(item.id, (item.quantity+1)) } className="btn font-weight-bolder">+</button>
                                    <button className="btn bg-white rounded">{item.quantity}</button>

                                    {
                                        item.quantity > 0 ? 
                                        <button className="btn font-weight-bolder" onClick={() => props.checkOutItemHandler(item.id, (item.quantity -1) )}>-</button>
                                        :
                                        <button disabled className="btn font-weight-bolder">-</button>

                                    }
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                  
                    <div className="cart-calculation">
                        <p className="d-flex justify-content-between"><span>Sub Total . {totalQuantity} Item</span> <span>${subTotal.toFixed(2)}</span></p>
                        <p className="d-flex justify-content-between"><span>Tax</span> <span>${tax.toFixed(2)}</span></p>
                        <p className="d-flex justify-content-between"><span>Delivery Fee</span> <span>${deliveryFee}</span></p>
                        <p className="h5 d-flex justify-content-between"><span>Total</span> <span>${grandTotal.toFixed(2)}</span></p>
                        {/* {
                            totalQuantity ?
                            paid? 
                                <Link to="/order-complete">
                                    <button onClick={() => props.clearCart()}  className="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-secondary">Check Out Your Food</button>
                                </Link>
                                :
                                <button disabled className="btn btn-block btn-secondary">Check Out Your Food</button>
                            :
                            <button disabled className="btn btn-block btn-secondary">Nothing to Checkout</button>

                    } */}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        //
        // <div className="shipment container">
        //     <h1>This is shipment</h1>
        //     <div className="row">
        //         <div className="">
        //             <h4>Edit Delivery Details</h4>
        //             <hr/>
        //             <form action="" className="py-5">
        //                 <div className="form-group">
        //                     <input type="text" name="todoor" className="form-control" ref={register({required: true})} defaultValue={todoor} placeholder="Delver to door" />
        //                     {errors && errors.todoor && <span className="error">This Option is required</span>}    
        //             </div>
        //             <div className="form-group">
        //                     <input type="text" name="road" className="form-control" ref={register({required: true})} defaultValue={road} placeholder="Road No" />
        //                     {errors && errors.road && <span className="error">This Option is required</span>}    
        //             </div>
        //             <div className="form-group">
        //                     <input type="text" name="flat" className="form-control" ref={register({required: true})} defaultValue={flat} placeholder="Flat, Suit Or Floor" />
        //                     {errors && errors.flat && <span className="error">This Option is required</span>}    
        //             </div>
        //             <div className="form-group">
        //                     <input type="text" name="business" className="form-control" ref={register({required: true})} defaultValue={business} placeholder="Business Name" />
        //                     {errors && errors.todoor && <span className="error">This Option is required</span>}    
        //             </div>
        //             <div className="form-group">
        //                     <input type="text" name="address" className="form-control" ref={register({required: true})} defaultValue={address} placeholder="Address" />
        //                     {errors && errors.address && <span className="error">This Option is required</span>}    
        //             </div>
        //                 <div className="form-group">
        //                     <button className="btn btn-danger">Save and Continue</button>
        //                 </div>

        //             </form>
        //         </div>
        //     </div>
        // </div>
    );
};

export default Shipment;
```

**Here is the error**

**TypeError: path.split is not a function**

```
get
T:/1.Full-Stack-Developer/5.React/3.Red Onion/src/utils/get.ts:6
  3 | import isUndefined from './isUndefined';
  4 | 
  5 | export default (obj: any = {}, path: string, defaultValue?: unknown) => {
> 6 |   const result = compact(path.split(/[,[\].]+?/)).reduce(
  7 |     (result, key) => (isNullOrUndefined(result) ? result : result[key]),
  8 |     obj,
  9 |   );
```

**renderWithHooks
T:/1.Full-Stack-Developer/5.React/3.Red Onion/red-onion-resturant/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985**

```
29 | <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="py-5">
  30 | 
  31 |     <div className="form-group">
> 32 |         <input  className="form-control" {...register( {requried: true})} defaultValue={todoor} placeholder="Delivery To Door"/>
     | ^  33 |         {errors && errors.todoor && <span className="error">This Option is required</span>}
  34 |     </div>
  35 |     <div className="form-group">
```

Answer (score 1):

- The array.compact() method doesn't work and also you can't declare
  the variable result and then pass it later as the accumulator.
- Try writing it this way:

```
export default (obj: any = {}, path: string, defaultValue?: unknown) => {
    return path.split(/[,[\].]+?/).reduce((result, key) => (
        isNullOrUndefined(result) ? result : result[key]
    ), obj)
}
```

Comment: May be my problem is shipment.js file. Within the react Hook form